In Pandas how do I flag the first weekend of each Half of the month?

Problem
This is my data I want to flag the first weekend between Day 1 and 15, and the first weekend between day 16 and 31. So, basically I want to flag the first Friday, Saturday, and Sunday for the FirstHalf and SecondHalf of the month.
Expected Result
2 flag columns

FirstWeekend_Flag =  where we flag the first weekend after the 1st and the first weekend after the 15th

RestWeekend_Flag = where we flag all the other weekends (not including FirstWeekend_Flag )



What do you want to do with partial weekend starts such as 2022-01 it starts on Saturday not Friday?

This is not a proper usage of Stack Overflow. You should not expect others to solve your problem, without explicitly showing any effort you have made to do it.

@Rarblack then dont answer

Yeah not answering, but voting to be closed!

Try this to capture the first full weekend starting on Friday.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2022-01-01', freq='D', periods=300)})

# Use np with datetimeindex accessor to get day of month
df['Half'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.day <= 15, 'FirstHalf', 'SecondHalf')
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day 
df['DayOfWeek'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofweek

# Check to see if day of the week is Friday to start the weekend
df['Friday?'] = (df['DayOfWeek'] == 4) 

# Use cumcount by month and half to get number of weekend start 
df['Weekend_Count'] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='Date'), 'Half'])['Friday?'].cumsum().mask(df['DayOfWeek']<4, 0).clip(0,2)
df['Weekend Flag'] = df['Weekend_Count'].mask(df['Weekend_Count'] == 0, '').map({1:'FirstWeekend_Flag', 2:'RestWeekend_Flag'})

df.head(50) #Sample first 50 days

Output:
         Date        Half  Day  DayOfWeek  Friday?  Weekend_Count       Weekend Flag
0  2022-01-01   FirstHalf    1          5    False              0                NaN
1  2022-01-02   FirstHalf    2          6    False              0                NaN
2  2022-01-03   FirstHalf    3          0    False              0                NaN
3  2022-01-04   FirstHalf    4          1    False              0                NaN
4  2022-01-05   FirstHalf    5          2    False              0                NaN
5  2022-01-06   FirstHalf    6          3    False              0                NaN
6  2022-01-07   FirstHalf    7          4     True              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
7  2022-01-08   FirstHalf    8          5    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
8  2022-01-09   FirstHalf    9          6    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
9  2022-01-10   FirstHalf   10          0    False              0                NaN
10 2022-01-11   FirstHalf   11          1    False              0                NaN
11 2022-01-12   FirstHalf   12          2    False              0                NaN
12 2022-01-13   FirstHalf   13          3    False              0                NaN
13 2022-01-14   FirstHalf   14          4     True              2   RestWeekend_Flag
14 2022-01-15   FirstHalf   15          5    False              2   RestWeekend_Flag
15 2022-01-16  SecondHalf   16          6    False              0                NaN
16 2022-01-17  SecondHalf   17          0    False              0                NaN
17 2022-01-18  SecondHalf   18          1    False              0                NaN
18 2022-01-19  SecondHalf   19          2    False              0                NaN
19 2022-01-20  SecondHalf   20          3    False              0                NaN
20 2022-01-21  SecondHalf   21          4     True              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
21 2022-01-22  SecondHalf   22          5    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
22 2022-01-23  SecondHalf   23          6    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
23 2022-01-24  SecondHalf   24          0    False              0                NaN
24 2022-01-25  SecondHalf   25          1    False              0                NaN
25 2022-01-26  SecondHalf   26          2    False              0                NaN
26 2022-01-27  SecondHalf   27          3    False              0                NaN
27 2022-01-28  SecondHalf   28          4     True              2   RestWeekend_Flag
28 2022-01-29  SecondHalf   29          5    False              2   RestWeekend_Flag
29 2022-01-30  SecondHalf   30          6    False              2   RestWeekend_Flag
30 2022-01-31  SecondHalf   31          0    False              0                NaN
31 2022-02-01   FirstHalf    1          1    False              0                NaN
32 2022-02-02   FirstHalf    2          2    False              0                NaN
33 2022-02-03   FirstHalf    3          3    False              0                NaN
34 2022-02-04   FirstHalf    4          4     True              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
35 2022-02-05   FirstHalf    5          5    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
36 2022-02-06   FirstHalf    6          6    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
37 2022-02-07   FirstHalf    7          0    False              0                NaN
38 2022-02-08   FirstHalf    8          1    False              0                NaN
39 2022-02-09   FirstHalf    9          2    False              0                NaN
40 2022-02-10   FirstHalf   10          3    False              0                NaN
41 2022-02-11   FirstHalf   11          4     True              2   RestWeekend_Flag
42 2022-02-12   FirstHalf   12          5    False              2   RestWeekend_Flag
43 2022-02-13   FirstHalf   13          6    False              2   RestWeekend_Flag
44 2022-02-14   FirstHalf   14          0    False              0                NaN
45 2022-02-15   FirstHalf   15          1    False              0                NaN
46 2022-02-16  SecondHalf   16          2    False              0                NaN
47 2022-02-17  SecondHalf   17          3    False              0                NaN
48 2022-02-18  SecondHalf   18          4     True              1  FirstWeekend_Flag
49 2022-02-19  SecondHalf   19          5    False              1  FirstWeekend_Flag

